# slick slider и z-index

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Здравствуйте. У меня есть пункты меню. Они в виде слайдера. хoчу сделать dropdown, но slick не дает отобразить выпадающее меню.
Вот проблема на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код:

```
<div class="autoplay">
    <div>   
        <a href="#">
            <div class="item dropdown">
                <img class="icon" src="img/icon1.png" alt="atl">
                <p class="item_p">Cтроительство<br>и ремонт</p>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <p>Hello World!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>    
    </div>
```

Стили:

```
.dropdown {
position: relative;
z-index: 99999!important;
}

.dropdown-content {
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
padding: 12px 16px;
z-index: 99999!important;
width: 200px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Рабочая ссылка с примером http://site.artem55555p.ru/

Comment: если я убираю у класса slick-list overflow, то меню видно, но тогда слайдер сам по себе едет...

Comment: position relative добавьте в свой класс p который внутри dropdown-content и посмотрите

Comment: @Избыток сусликов добавил, ничего не изменилось....

Comment: в смысле не изменилось вы должны были увидеть содержимое тега p

Comment: @Избыток сусликов  ну перейдите по ссылке и посмотрите, там нет ничего..

Comment: просто в консоли измените  свойство класса dropdown-content position:absolute на relative и скажите мне

Comment: @Избыток сусликов  да, так видно. но так слайдер растягивается по высоте. а мне нужно, чтобы как обычный dropdown был